# No puedo crear un componente en Angular Cli 9.1.6

Tags: angular

Estimados estoy realizando un curso de angular 9 y en el curso crean un componente pero en mi caso no puedo crearlo debido a que no se reconoce la opción --spec.

Estoy intentando crear dentro de "app" ,una carpeta llamada "shared" y una subcarpeta dentro llamada header y en esa subcarpeta deberían crearse unos archivos css y html pero el comando no me funciona.

mi comando es : ng g c shared/header --spec=false

Aquí el Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería crear la carpeta shared y una subcarpeta llamada header y dentro de esa subcarpeta debería crearse unos archivos pero no se están creando debido al error.
por favor me podrían ayudar orientándome.

Answer (score 2):

En la versión 9 de angular cli la opción de no generar ficheros spec se ha sustituido por `--skipTests=true|false`.

Por defecto `--skipTests` es false.

```
ng g c shared/header --skipTests=true
```

[Aquí](https://angular.io/cli/generate) la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría un simple ng g c shared/header, lo cual también te creará el archivo spec.ts de testing. Simplemente, después puedes borrarlo y quedarte con el resto (es recomendable mantenerlo aunque no hagas testing ahora mismo). Si te da algún tipo de error, crea primero la carpeta shared dentro de app.